# fbprophet library error while installing: name 'HolidayBase' is not defined

Tags: python, time-series

When I tried to install the fbprophet library for Python, I faced the following error:

> name 'HolidayBase' is not defined

and it took me a while to get the solution. That's why I'm answering my own question, in case it helps someone.

Comment: It would probably be better if you'd open an issue on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to downgrade my Python version from **3.7.3** to **3.6.7**.

I did not do an extensive analysis on to which other versions work - maybe all 3.6 do.